# How can I set up dropdown lists used to provide Stored Procedure parameters to SSRS reports to accept multiple values?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I need to allow the user to select 1..N of a particular parameter when generating an SSRS report. According to this [otherwise very helpful blog post](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2844/working-with-multiselect-parameters-for-ssrs-reports/), that's possible, but its instructions in Step 5 to "Set the Properties of both parameters" has me clawing my noggin.

What two ("both") parameters? In the Preview tab I see the dropdown list, but right-clicking doesn't afford any contextual menu items. The other ("Design") tab shows no dropdown list, of course.

So from where is the "Allow multiple values" checkbox Step 5 mentions accessible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get to the parameter properties in Design mode (design tab), not preview mode. Double-click on any parameter under the parameters folder in the Report Data pane. (If the Report Data pane is not visible, Ctrl-Alt-D will show it) There, under General, is where you set the Allow multiple values option.